# RAM info with dmidecode --type 17

Tags: linux, memory, железо, ram

На материнской плате ASUS V-PRO Z77 установлены 2х2 (Kingston и Corsair) планок оперативной памяти. Все четыре планки оперативной памяти нареканий в работе не вызывают. Работают исправно. Но, ниже представлен вывод результата запуска программы Dmidecode и в выводе меня интересуют следующие строки:

```
Error Information Handle: 0x0060  
Error Information Handle: 0x0063
```

**Что это значит и с чем связана такая информация?**

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type 17
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0x000f04c0
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x005B, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005C
    Error Information Handle: 0x0060
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 9333B00B
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 99U5584-007.A00LF 
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x005F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005C
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: 029E
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x0062, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005C
    Error Information Handle: 0x0063
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 1D10C373
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 99U5584-018.A00LF 
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x0065, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005C
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: 029E
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz
```

**UPD**

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type 18
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0x000f04c0
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x005D, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0060, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0063, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0066, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это значит, что информация об ошибках находится в других записях с номерами `0x0060` и `0x0063` соответственно.

Дабы узнать, что за ними скрывается `dmidecode` следует запустить без параметров и просмотреть вывод. Номера handel'ов указываются в заголовках в выводе следующим образом:

> **Handle 0x005B**, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
>   Memory Device

Вероятно их тип будет 18 (32-bit Memory Error Information) или 33 (64-bit Memory Error Information).

По всей видимости само наличие значения в поле `Error Information Handle` покуда в структуре на которую он ссылается значение `Type: OK`. Как именно представляются данные определяется реализацией.

Comment: А о чём эти ошибки?

Comment: а я откуда знаю =), в выводе же их нет...

Comment: А как же выяснить? Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ilmirabdulmanov, запусти `dmidecode` и посмотри что скрывается за этими ручками... вероятно их тип будет 18 или 33.

Comment: вы угадали. Есть Handle 0x0060, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
 Type: OK
 Granularity: Unknown
 Operation: Unknown
 Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
 Memory Array Address: Unknown
 Device Address: Unknown
 Resolution: Unknown
Аналогично для 0x0063
Но что это значит для меня всё еще не понятно. Подскажите, плиз)

Comment: `Memory Error Information Type: OK` — звучит как будто всё в порядке...

Comment: Согласен с вами. Но для Corsair и вовсе No Errors. Поэтому хочется выяснить к чему это может привести. Может вернуть продавцу эти плашки (Kingston).

Comment: ИМХО просто отличия в реализации... понимаю, что паранойя штука тяжёлая, но в данном случае нет причин волноваться))... если совсем туго, то можно memtest пару дней погонять и убедится, что ошибок не последовало...